# How to integrate exponential of complicated expressions

Tags: integration, substitution

say I have to integrate the following:
$e^{(x^2 + bx )}$
w.r.t x

How can it be done.. I have tried taking $x^2+bx = t$ but I am stuck at $(2x + b)dx = dt$

Comment: the solution containes the Error-function

Comment: Not all functions have closed-form antiderivatives.  There is no function $\int e^{x^2 + bx}dx$ that can be expressed in terms of the usual functions.

Answer (score 0):

$t=x+\frac{b}{2}\\
dt=dx\\
t^2=x^2+bx+\frac{b^2}{4}\\
x^2+bx = t^2 - \frac{b^2}{4}$

We have then:
$\int e^{x^2+bx}dx = e^{-\frac{b^2}{4}}\int e^{t^2} dt$

But $\int e^{t^2} dt$ is non-elementary. Therefore this integral can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions.